# How to export a picture with guidelines from CorelDraw?

Tags: export, corel-draw, guides

Can I export a picture with guidelines from CorelDraw?

[image]

Those dashed lines are all is guidelines, created by dragging from the left ruler.

[image]

I want to export this whole file and **include those guidelines**. Is this possible?

Comment: What is subline? the dotted lines? Export to what? What have you tried?

Comment: @Luciano I draw it one by one in current method.So I want to get a better solution.

Comment: Why can't you export what you already have? Your question isn't very clear

Comment: @Cai The picture in the post is by a screen-shot..I hope to export by software itself

Comment: So have you tried exporting the image? Are you having a problem? Perhaps read the user manual - it seems to be quite in-depth with whole sections devoted to exporting images for output: http://product.corel.com/help/CorelDRAW/540238885/Main/EN/User-Guide/CorelDRAW-X8.pdf

Comment: @BillyKerr Of course,I have exported it,but the image exported don't include auxiliary line.This question is about how to export a image with auxiliary line..Feel tired to explain these..

Comment: @yode you can't expect others to just guess and figure out what your problem is. You've explained next to nothing in your question; what exactly are those lines and how did you create them? How are you currently exporting and why didn't that work?

Comment: ...just a guess but are those actually *guides*?

Comment: @Cai I just cannot why my description will lead to so many misunderstanding,I just want export those auxiliary line.

Comment: Because they are called guides or guidelines not auxiliary lines, so it wasn't clear at all what you were asking. As far as I know you can't export guidelines with your image, they're not meant to be exported at all. You'll more than likely just have to use the guidelines to manually draw dashed lines

Comment: @Cai I know it not meant to be exported.But I want to export it still,I think there are some people also having such demand.It's a hard question maybe.So I request a solution here.

Comment: But they're not meant to be exported, they are meant to be guides to draw actual lines so just use the guides to draw actual lines. That shouldn't take more than a few minutes. Maybe there is a better solution but I havn't used CorelDraw in years so I don't know.

Comment: In short: the guidelines are not part of the drawing, draw your lines and style them as dotted / dashed and you'll be able to export it. You don't have to draw them one by one if you learn how to duplicate objects. As Billy suggested, you can find all this information in the manual.

Comment: @Luciano If those guidelines have equal distance,then we can use `ctrl+d` to duplicate it.But it is not.

Comment: @yode you can always reposition it using constraints after duplicating the lines. Sorry but I don't see a better method in this case.

Comment: @yode CorelDraw has a "View > snap to > guidelines" feature - shown on page 227 of the user manual. Use that to position the duplicated lines.

Answer (score 3):

They can be exported but only in some formats.

Here are several options:

Use the > Object Manager docker

**Turn on the little printer icon**. There are two types of guides, normal and master page guides.

[image]

I tested and they can be exported to PDF but not to PNG for example.

### 1. PDF Export

Here is a simple screen capture of the pdf as viewed on Adobe reader.
[image]

If you now open again this PDF inside Corel, all guides are now converted to simple lines, and you now can change color, width and style.

[image]

### 2. Another option is that they can be printed

Again, turn on the little printer icon and print the image to a **virtual printer** like PDF creator.

On PDF creator you can configure the type of file you need. I recommend you export the double the resolution you need because this way of "exporting" does not apply an anti-alias, so you can reduce the resolution by half with a bicubic algorithm to put an anti-alias on the image.

I do not like much this method because you can not control the look very well. The only way to control it is changing the export resolution, so they "look wider" then printed wider.

Printed at 600ppi
[image]

Resampled in half resolution
[image]

---

### 3. Make a new layer and draw lines

Prepare a new layer and draw lines there, so you can control the type of dotted line, color, transparency and width of the stroke.

Make one line in this new layer and just copy it and drag it to snap to the existing guides. Snap in Corel is pretty accurate.

> View > Snap to > Guidelines

---

### 4. Use normal lines as guides from start.

Remember that you can snap to any object in Corel Draw, so simple lines (in a special layer to keep them organized) can be used as guidelines.

> View > Snap to > All